# Disk Scheduler in Linux

Tags: linux, hard-disk, scheduling

I am studying about Disk Scheduling in my OS class. Thought about the disk scheduler in Linux. When I run

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler 
noop anticipatory deadline [cfq]
```

Someone explain about this noop anticipatory deadline [cfq]. Text books says scan, cscan, look, fifo, sstf...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That means that four schedulers are available, `noop`, `anticipatory`, `deadline`, and `cfq`. Currently, `cfq` is active. See [Selecting a Linux I/O Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009577/selecting-a-linux-i-o-scheduler/1010562#1010562).